Ratchet can't broadcast data to the clients
Here the logic is to send data in realtime from this controller at first time flutter developer will call the endpoint to trigger the broadcasting function then when i make new order in ordercontroller in createOrder i will broadcast new data so he will only open the connection and listen to changes .
The problem is when I test the endpoint it can't send any data to the online clients and when i debug the $clients array is empty every time inside the broadcast function.
In the onOpen and onClose functions $clients exists but why is it empty in the broadcast function?
I ensured that the instance is a singleton.
class OrderWebSocketServer implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;
    private static $instance = null;
    protected $copyClients=[];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        $this->copyClients=$this->clients;
        echo "Total connected clients: " . $this->clients->count() . "\n";
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

  
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        // dd(self::$instance);
       
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function onClose(Connection Interface $conn)
    {

        echo "Total connected clients: " . count($this->clients) . "\n";
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }

    public function broadcast($data)
    {
        // Debugging: Output the number of connected clients
        // echo "Broadcasting to " . $this->clients->count() . " clients\n";
        echo "Total: " . count($this->copyClients) . "\n";

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            $client->send(json_encode($data));
        }

        //echo "Broadcasting data: " . json_encode($data) . "\n"; // Debug output
    }
}
class ObserverHomeRealTimeTestController extends Controller
{
    

    public function updateStream()
    {
        $garageId = Auth::user()->garage_id;

        $orderQuery = $this->buildOrderQuery($garageId);

        $pendingOrders = $this->getPendingOrders($orderQuery);
        $currentOrders = $this->getCurrentOrders($orderQuery);
        $finishedOrders = $this->getFinishedOrders($orderQuery);

        $lastObserverAttendance = $this->getLastObserverAttendance();

        $data = [
            'observer_attendance' => $lastObserverAttendance->action ?? 'Checkout',
            'pending_orders' => HomeResource::collection($pendingOrders)->response()->getData(true),
            'current_orders' => HomeResource::collection($currentOrders)->response()->getData(true),
            'finished_orders' => HomeResource::collection($finishedOrders)->response()->getData(true),
         
        ];

        $wsServer = OrderWebSocketServer::getInstance();
        // $dds='ssss';
        // dd($wsServer);
        $wsServer->broadcast($data);
    }


It's not obvious how or why the clients list would be empty just because you called a different function. Can you provide a [mre] of the issue which shows how you're actually using the class and calling the functions? You can [edit] your question - please pay attention to the formatting when doing so, and check the preview before posting. Thanks.

getinstance method call in controller to broadcast data to the same object of type splObject and it's singleton so where i oben connection in front end vanilla javascript the onOpen function print the online clients number and it's id and when closed the page the connection closed and onclose function see the client that detach and number of online clients but when i call api that call broadcast function and send data through it to the clients the data already inject in the method but clients array was empty and i donot have the reason of it

Again, please show relevant code, we cannot fix a description! And [edit] your question to add all clarification, including your description, to the question, not the comments area. And lastly if you're going to add that description please put some punctuation into it! It's almost unreadable right now, because we can't tell where the sentences begin and end. Thanks

You still haven't shown us any code explaining how you are actually interacting with the socket server in each scenario - you mention an order controller, but seems the code you've provided is from some other test code. If I had to guess, you've somehow ended up with two different instances of the socket server running (despite your singleton code), but without a [mre] of that we can't really be sure what has happened, or how it happened. A description only takes us so far, really we need to see relevant code, in context, to be certain
